# Replace the property value in the placeholder in a java attribute - IntelliJ 2017.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, placeholder

I noticed that IntelliJ replaces the value of the property in the placeholder. When the mouse is over the value this shows the name of the property, this works well with XML files.

[image]

I like this functionality and I was wondering if is there any way to do the same in java attributes? for example:

**class:**

```
@Service
public class PropertyService {

    //@Value("My demo App")
    @Value(${project.name})
    private String projectName;

}
```

**application.properties**

```
project.name=My demo App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it works only in XML files, I've [submitted a request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175797) to add support for other file types (like Java and Kotlin). Please follow YouTrack ticket for updates.

Comment: great! it will be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure since which version is working but I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 Ultimate Edition and using `@Value` annotation from Spring Beans it's already working for properties in your application.properties

[image]

Comment: It was my mistake not to specify the version in which I tested, it was in 2017.2, this functionality is available since build [173.3170](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070165/replace-the-property-value-in-the-placeholder-in-a-java-attribute-intellij-201), that is, from the IntelliJ version 2017.3